# REST on IIS 7.5 - IIS specified authentication schemes Exception

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

First, the Service is working correctly on a Server 2008 environment with IIS 7.5. Same Service on a Windows 7/IIS 7.5 environment shows the following error:

```
[InvalidOperationException: IIS specified authentication schemes 'IntegratedWindowsAuthentication, Anonymous', but the binding only supports specification of exactly one authentication scheme. Valid authentication schemes are Digest, Negotiate, NTLM, Basic, or Anonymous. Change the IIS settings so that only a single authentication scheme is used.]
   System.ServiceModel.Web.WebServiceHost.SetBindingCredentialBasedOnHostedEnvironment(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, AuthenticationSchemes supportedSchemes) +349683
   System.ServiceModel.Web.WebServiceHost.AddAutomaticWebHttpBindingEndpoints(ServiceHost host, IDictionary`2 implementedContracts, String multipleContractsErrorMessage, String standardEndpointKind) +806
   System.ServiceModel.Web.WebServiceHost.OnOpening() +244
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout) +274
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open() +36
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(String normalizedVirtualPath) +184
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath) +615

[ServiceActivationException: The service '/IMonSapService' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: IIS specified authentication schemes 'IntegratedWindowsAuthentication, Anonymous', but the binding only supports specification of exactly one authentication scheme. Valid authentication schemes are Digest, Negotiate, NTLM, Basic, or Anonymous. Change the IIS settings so that only a single authentication scheme is used..]
   System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +687598
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +190
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.AspNetRouteServiceHttpHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +6
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +96
```

I have the following line in my Global.asax.cs

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("IMonSapService", new WebServiceHostFactory(),
                    typeof(IMonSapService)));
```

Here the first lines of the Service implementation

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements
    (RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class IMonSapService : IIMonSapService
{
...
}
```

My web.config looks like this

```
 <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" />
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
```

I compared the two IIS instances but I didn't found a difference.

Comment: Please add screenshots of activated (and installed) authentications on windows2008 and windows7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this in applicationHost.config

```
<authentication>
    <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" userName="IUSR"/>
    <basicAuthentication enabled="false"/>
    <clientCertificateMappingAuthentication/>
    <digestAuthentication/>
    <iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication/>
    <windowsAuthentication enabled="true"/>
</authentication>
```

Changing windowsAuthentication to

```
    <windowsAuthentication enabled="false"/>
```

solved the problem. I thought in IIS Manager/Authentication everything was disabled but I had to change also this in the config file.